# retrieve attachment from facebook message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

How to fetch attachment i.e added photos or files from message using Facebook C# SDK. I'm able to fetch message as json response but did not see any key for attachment in it.

For example

I have replied the message with image added.

When I retrieved Message item from facebook using Facebook C# SDK as

```
FacebookClient fbclient = new FacebookClient("AccessToken");
fbclient.get("me\inbox"),
```

I did not see the entry of image. Replies are in comments part.

Json response I received from the above query is as follows:

```
    {
      "data": [
       {

  "id": "1234567890123456",
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "id": "100001234567890"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "id": "100001234567891"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jack Smith",
        "id": "100001234567892"
      }
    ]
  },
  "updated_time": "2012-12-04T11:28:18+0000",
  "unread": 0,
  "unseen": 0,
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1234567890123456_1",
        "from": {
          "name": "Jack Smith",
          "id": "100001234567891"
        },
        "message": "attachment testing",
        "created_time": "2012-12-04T11:28:18+0000"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890123456/comments?limit=25&since=1234567890&__paging_token=1234567890123456_3",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890123456/comments?limit=25&until=1234567890&__paging_token=1234567890123456_1"
    }
  }
    ]
```

Reply is in comment part. I have attached the image in the reply too. But I did not see the entry of the image.

Comment: You should include more info, like the JSON response you're receiving and the exact call you're making to get get it.

Comment: I have added more info into the original question.